# Flow js: How to show the definition with the types detailed

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, webstorm, atom-editor, flow-js

I looked for in VSCode, Atom and WebStorm but could not find any showing the detailed type which where previously declared. Here an example from VSCode:

```
type Props = {| propTest: string |};

export const TestFlow1 = (props:Props) => {
  return <div />;
};

export const TestFlow2 = (props: {| propTest: string |}) => {
 return <div />;
};
```

Hovering  in VSCode, the definition appears like this:

[image]

Which is useless to know the props and corresponding types.

When the types are define "directly" as for TestFlow2, the props and types appear:

[image]

Is there a configuration or a plugin, so declaring the types as in the first example it can be shown the definition as in the second example? And that for either: VSCode, WebStorm or Atom.